# Display text inside button in one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button with some text inside it, it displays the text in one line, which is okay, but when I center the button using `display:block` then the button is centered which is fine but the text inside it has a line break and is divided in two lines, I want the text only to be displayed in one line:
This is my code:

```
<div class="MyClass"><a type="button" style="margin:auto; display:block" class="ButtonLink" href="@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")">Selected Now</a></div>
```

When I have my code like this the text is displayed in one line but I need to center the button:

```
<div class="MyClass"><a type="button" class="ButtonLink" href="@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")">Selected Now</a></div>
```

This is what I want:

[image]

And this is how the text is displayed when I center the button:

[image]

What do I need to do?

Comment: Where is your definition of `.ButtonLink` ?

Comment: whats the CSS on the button?  maybe decrease left/right padding, text-align center

Comment: hi, have u got the solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: nowrap`.

```
<div class="MyClass">
    <a type="button" class="ButtonLink" href="@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")">Selected Now</a>
</div>
```

```css
.ButtonLink {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
```